# Golfing match with Jim, Joanne, Ed, and Emily

Tags: logical-deduction

Jim, Joanne, Ed, and Emily are standing on the first tee of their favorite golf course, about to begin a partners match, (A partners match pits two golfers against two other golfers). They are standing in a square; two standing next to each other on the cart path, directly facing the other two standing next to each other on the grass. They all shake hands, then one of them throws a tee in the air and lets it hit the ground. Whoever it points to will tee off first.

Jim is standing diagonally opposite Emily. Joanne is facing the person whose name begins with the same letter as that of the name of the person who will tee off first. Partners tee off one after the other. Who will tee off second?

Answer (score 2):

The person who will tee off second is

> Emily

The formation is as follows, with the line dividing the partners (assuming that the partner pairings are standing on the same turf):

> Jim    Joanne
>  ----- 
>  Ed     Emily

or

> Jim    Ed
>  ----- 
>  Joanne    Emily

It doesn't matter which permutation.

Explanation:

> Jim and Emily are given to be standing diagonally to one another. However this works out, they are on **opposite** teams.
> Joanne's placement is across from the person whose name starts with the same letter as the person who tees off first. Her options are to stand across from either Emily or Jim. This means that either:
> A) Joanne stands across from Emily, whose name starts with E which in turn implies that Ed tees off first (occupying the last remaining space in the square formation) and his teammate Emily tees off second, or
> B) Joanne stands across from Jim, whose name starts with J which in turn implies that Joanne tees off first and her teammate Emily tees off second.
> As is now clear, Emily tees off second in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

## My answer

> Emily

## My explanation

> We know Jim and Emily are diagonal from one another. We also know Joanne is facing someone who has the first initial of the person teeing off first. This means Joanne cannot be on Emily's team because Joanne could never face someone that has the same first initial as the person teeing off first. So this places Joanne on Jim's team, directly opposing Emily, who is the partner of another E person, Ed. Since Ed is hitting first, his partner, Emily is hitting second.

Comment: Sorry buddy, beat you to it. Also, notice in my answer that rot13(Wbnaar pna or ba Rzvyl'f grnz).

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Answer looks good except for as stated above someone beat you to it. Make sure to check if someone has already said an answer you plan to before posting. Stick around and I'm sure you will be the first to correctly answer a question soon.

Comment: @kanoo Indeed, congrats! rot13(V qvqa'g guvax nobhg gur frpbaq crezhgngvba. Gunaxf sbe znxvat zr tb onpx naq gnxr n ybbx.)